# Unable to set iptables in Ubuntu in AWS. Should I use ufw instead?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, iptables

, because of security reason I do not want to run my server (node.js) in port 80, so I would like to redirect incoming traffic from port 8080 to port 80 in my aws EC2 instance.. I have tried this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

I even tried "sudo". However, when I run sudo iptables -L, there is still nothing.  Just like that:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Why it doesn't work?

should I use ufw instead?  does it work well in AWS EC2 Ubuntu 13.0+ instance?

Answer (score 0):

`iptables -L` will only show you the FILTER table by default.  Try `iptables -L -t nat` and you should see your rules.